# is it safe ignoring context.mounted access linting error on an async function?

Tags: flutter

I have an async function to logout which waits for a call and then it redirects to the first screen.
the linter complaints I'm accessing the context object to check if it's mounted, but I'm just checking if it is, in order to proceed. Because of that I've put an ignore comment:

```dart
  _logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    await Supabase.instance.client.auth.signOut();

    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    if (!context.mounted) return;

    Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Intro.routeName, (_) => false);
  }
```

the question: I don't know if ignoring in this very particular case is safe. Can you confirm? Is there another way to accomplish this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an experimental lint rule and what you have done is in fact recommended.

It might get fixed in later versions in flutter.

You can access more info below

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html

Edit:
There seems to be some analytical error with how this is evaluated because following code does not produce lint warning

```dart
 _logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 8));

    if (context.mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Intro.routeName, (_) => false);
    }
  }
```

But if you add any operator with `context.mounted`, it results in warning. for example `if(!context.mounted)` or `if(context.mounted ==false)`.

I have opened a github-issue on dart-sdk as well.
https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/4223